# python bundled by py2app still points to local path

Tags: py2app

I would like to create a macOS app using `py2app`. My application (testapp) has a few dependencies
(`paramiko`,`scp`,`PyYAML`,`PyQt5`). To do so:

1. I installed `python3` using brew (located in `/usr/local/Cellar`).
2. I installed the aforementioned dependencies in this python
3. I ran `python3 setup.py py2app --packages paramiko,yaml,scp`

Everything runs apparently fine. I have a `testapp.app` directory created in dist. However, when I run the python located in the bundle (`./dist/testapp.app/Contents/MacOS/python`) I run into troubles. Indeed, I can import the aforementioned external packages but when I inspect their path, the result gives me the local installation and not the one of the bundle.

For instance `paramiko.__path__` gives me: `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko`

Looking deeper into the bundle, I could not find the file `site-packages.zip` which should be created by py2app.

As such my bundle is absolutely not self consistent and can not be distributed on other machines. Would you have any idea about what is wrong with my setup ?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I started to inspect the embedded python because running the embedded app failed.

Comment: First of all: don’t run the embedded copy of python like that.  Does “dist/testapp.app/Contents/MacOS/testapp” work?  That is a small launcher program that sets up the right environment.

Comment: no, the   dist/testapp.app/Contents/MacOS/testapp` fails also. That's the reason why I started to inspect what was there in the embedded python

Comment: How does it fail?  Do you get the same failure when you use the Python.org installer instead of homebrew?

Comment: It complains about loading dynamic library (imp.pyc -- 343 -- load_dynamic --). I have no yet tried with a Python.org installation.